# How to purchase consumable product more than one time via in-app purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app

After going through number of question still i haven't receive any to the point solution. In one of my Iphone application i'm using in-app purchase payment method. As per requirement i have created consumable product but after first purchase it gives me a message on second purchase that product is already buy for the same product. Requirement is something like this, for one added item user can buy three different time slot and for every slot user need to pay. So for item(I1), user add timeslot (T1) and pay for the same, then add timeslot(T2) and pay for the same.

Comment: Check if your in app purchase is really consumable, probably, you have created non-consumable iap.

Comment: I've create consumable type product only. But their one point that prior to that i've created a subscription type product and delete the same. After that i've create this consumable product as per my app requirement but it gives me that product is already purchased after first purchase. Do you think due to this i'm getting this issue??

Comment: You must have forgotten to delete some code in your app that is preventing you to purchase something that has been already purchased. Check you IAPHelper.m (or something similar) for this.

Comment: I've check the same what you have suggested but still i'm not able to resolve the same. Can you please share the code snippets or working demo for the same so that i can utilize the same for further proceedings. It would be great help..!!!

Comment: If found any solution please post the answer